# WPF Override style from a style trigger

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Radiobutton, which has styling set to make it appear as a ToggleButton, and I want to set its default background color to green, but when it is active/checked i want it to change color.  In my example below I'd like it to be blue.  No matter what I try the green color never gets overridden.  What am I missing?

Button:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Rating" Background="Green" Style="{StaticResource RatingToggleButtons}" x:Name="Normal" Content="Normal" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Style:

```
        <Style x:Key="RatingToggleButtons" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 5 5 5" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>            
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Short,background applied via control template has upper hand, compared to background set via Style (your case.) So you need to edit control template.

```
  <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TValue="#FF838383"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
```

note : code not tested

Refer to : http://www.diranieh.com/NET_WPF/Properties.htm

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

The fact that local values take precedence over values set by styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

So instead of setting a local value like this:

```
<RadioButton ... Background="Green" ... />
```

...you should define the default value in the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 5 5 5" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

...and again avoid setting the `Background` property of the `RadioButton` element:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Rating" Style="{StaticResource RatingToggleButtons}" x:Name="Normal" Content="Normal" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Comment: I have a bunch of RadioButtons I'd like to apply this to.  I assume I'd set the individual colors using a binding property?

Comment: You can override the default value by setting the local Background property. Whether you set it using a binding doesn't matter.

Comment: if i set a local background value the trigger never takes effect though.  If i remove the local value it works as expected.

Comment: Yes. This is the expected behaviour as stated in my answer.

Comment: I'm new to WPF, so my comments may not make sense, but basically i have a group of controls all with different initial colors, which I'd like to apply this style to and have them all change to the same color when checked.  The style above only accommodates them being the same initial color and then change to blue upon being checked.