# WPF, My IsMouseOver of my Grid doesnt change the Backgroundcolor

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid x:Name="set_bg" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="90" Background="Transparent" MouseDown="set_bg_MouseDown">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Image Height="66" Opacity="0.7" Source="/Images/settings.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"/>
</Grid>
```

I don't really know why this doesn't work, even though everything should be fine

Comment: This answer may help you: [WPF Override style from a style trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109450/9365244)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `Background="Transparent"`.
The trigger actually is changing the background color, but it is not possible to see when it set to transparent.